# register mount command for a custom filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fuse, mount-point

In both, mount command arguments and in /etc/fstab entries, we specify the filesystem of a mount point by its name, for exp. ext4, ntfs-3g, hfsplus

How does a linux system now how to properly mount each filesystem by name?

Is it possible to register a mount method for:

1. a kernel space filesystem (ko)
2. register a user space filesystem (fuse)

Comment: *How does a linux system now how to properly mount each filesystem by name*. The kernel module that supports each file system registers the name with the kernel.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit how exactly its done?

Comment: It's nothing magical. Kernel module code calls a register function, [register_filesystem](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5b8b9d0c6d0e0f1993c6c56deaf9646942c49d94/fs/filesystems.c#L72), and the parameter passed to the function provides info about the file system including its name.